# Filter out Text with Xpath in Google Docs

Tags: html, xpath, google-docs

I'm using Google Docs to capture Business names, addresses and phone numbers. So far the formula below works perfectly on the site I'm using except for one small smidgeon of a problem in the text for the phone numbers on the website it is Phone: XXX-XXX-XXXX. I do not want Xpath to copy 'Phone:' I tried using the formula like this and it is not working.

//td[replace('Phone:', '')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression.**

You need to get every value and then you can evaluate this XPath 1.0 expression on it:

```
substring-after(., 'Phone: ')
```

In case you can use XPath 2.0, I would recommend this one-liner:

```
//td/substring-after(., 'Phone: ')
```